# WCF - Foreach loop to insert records into a database

Tags: c#, wcf, stored-procedures

I'm working on WCF project. I am trying to insert multiple records into my SQL Server database from an array.

when calling the service, I get an exception :"Procedure or function has too many arguments specified", while my arguments in my function are in confirmity with those declared in my stored procedure :

Here is my function in WCF :

```
    public static string SetGaranties( List<int> CODE_GARANTIES,  string NUMERO_POLICE, string CODE_BRANCHE, int CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE)
    {
        string MSG_ACQUITEMENT = string.Empty;
        DbCommand com = GenericData.CreateCommand(GenericData.carte_CarteVie_dbProviderName, GenericData.Carte_CarteVie_dbConnectionString);

        com.CommandText = "SetGaranties";

        com.Parameters.Clear();

        foreach (int CODE_GARANTIE in CODE_GARANTIES)
        {
            com.Connection.Open();
            SqlParameter NUMERO_POLICE_Param = new SqlParameter("@NUMERO_POLICE", NUMERO_POLICE);
            com.Parameters.Add(NUMERO_POLICE_Param);

            SqlParameter CODE_BRANCHE_Param = new SqlParameter("@CODE_BRANCHE", CODE_BRANCHE);
            com.Parameters.Add(CODE_BRANCHE_Param);

            SqlParameter CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE_Param = new SqlParameter("@CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE", CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE);
            com.Parameters.Add(CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE_Param);

            SqlParameter CODE_POSTALE_Param = new SqlParameter("@CODE_GARANTIE", CODE_GARANTIE);
            com.Parameters.Add(CODE_POSTALE_Param);
            DbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            com.Connection.Close();                     

        }
```

and here is my Stored procedure :

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SetGaranties]    
@NUMERO_POLICE     varchar(12),
@CODE_BRANCHE   varchar(1),
@CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE  int,
@CODE_GARANTIE  int
AS  
BEGIN  
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.MVT_GARANTIES VALUES(
@NUMERO_POLICE,
@CODE_BRANCHE,
@CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE,
@CODE_GARANTIE
);
END
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm not an expert with SQL Server, but a similar things occur with Oracle. I think you have to specify the type of arguments with SqlDbType and set the value afterward according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
com.Parameters.Clear();
```

Should be inside your loop. With the current code the first iteration should have the correct number of parameters. But subsequent iterations will have too many because the the param list isn't being cleared.

Answer (score 2):

Build the parameters outside the loop just once, set the invariant values outside the loop and inside the loop just set only the one value that changes at each loop

```
public static string SetGaranties( List<int> CODE_GARANTIES,  string NUMERO_POLICE, string CODE_BRANCHE, int CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE)
{
    string MSG_ACQUITEMENT = string.Empty;
    DbCommand com = GenericData.CreateCommand(GenericData.carte_CarteVie_dbProviderName, GenericData.Carte_CarteVie_dbConnectionString);
    com.CommandText = "SetGaranties";
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // These parameter's values don't change, set it once
    com.Parameters.Add("@NUMERO_POLICE", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = NUMERO_POLICE;
    com.Parameters.Add("@CODE_BRANCHE",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CODE_BRANCHE;
    com.Parameters.Add("@CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CODE_SOUS_BRANCHE;

    // This parameter's value changes inside the loop
    com.Parameters.Add("@CODE_GARANTIE",SqlDbType.Int);

    com.Connection.Open();
    foreach (int CODE_GARANTIE in CODE_GARANTIES)
    {
        com.Parameters["@CODE_GARANTIE"].Value = CODE_GARANTIE;
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    com.Connection.Close();                     
}
```

Other things to say:

- You are using a global connection object, this usually is a very bad
  idea. ADO.NET implements connection pooling and this means that you
  should create your connection when you need it and destroy it
  afterwards.
- ExecuteNonQuery should be used when you INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE records.
  No need to build an SqlDataReader when you don't have anything to
  read back.
- A Stored Procedure is executed only if you set the CommandType to
  StoredProcedure otherwise you get a syntax error because the
  CommandText is not a valid Sql Statement

Comment: I agree with you, but the OP thinks differently.

Comment: using `CommandType.Text`, the default type, sql server will wrap the command in sp_executesql however, in this case, named parameters must be used (which the OP does) - using the `StoredProcedure` type will make it faster however this may be micro-optimization here, Specification of the type here to me also lends clarity of purpose.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss if we omit the CommandType.StoredProcedure then we need to supply the parameters on the same string with the name of the SP. Like _`"SetGaranties @NUMERO_POLICE,...."`._ I have always found that syntax confusing. I prefer to state the CommandType.StoredProcedure.